# Ошибка в discord.py, не понимаю как исправить

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

````py
import discord
import asyncio
import requests
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('/play'):
        search = message.content[6:]
        query = urllib.parse.quote(search)
        url = f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={query}"
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
        vid = soup.find_all('a', class_='yt-uix-tile-link')[0]
        video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com' + vid['href']
        channel = message.author.voice.channel
        voice = await channel.connect()
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(video_url)
        voice.play(source)
        while voice.is_playing():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await voice.disconnect()

client.run('TOKEN') ```
````

При выполнении команды /play (название музыки)

Выдает ошибку:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\artem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\bot.py", line 25, in on_message
    vid = soup.find_all('a', class_='yt-uix-tile-link')[0]
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range ```
````

Comment: Скорее всего на странице не нашлось ни одного элемента, который удовлетворил бы данному паттерну поиска. Поэтому выход за границы списка - `list index out of range`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка  возникает из-за того что когда пытаетесь получить доступ к элементу списка, который не существует, то есть индекс выходит за границы списка.

Можно добавить такой код он проверит, есть ли элементы в списке vid перед попыткой получить доступ к первому элементу

```
vid = soup.find_all('a', class_='yt-uix-tile-link')
if len(vid) > 0:
    video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com' + vid[0]['href']
    то что-то делаем и тут какой-то еще код
   
else:
    await message.channel.send("Не удалось найти видео.")
```